# Configuring Springboot to work with 2 different databases

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-boot

I am just learning how to use springboot as a java backend framework and I currently have `applications.properties` configured to use 1 database.

I am thinking of adding an additional database to store different information instead of saving everything on a single database so I was wondering how (if possible) can i do that?

My application.properties file contains data like this:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just need two data sources with separate bean or JNDI names, each with their own connection URLs, drivers, and credentials.

Answer (score 3):

You can create two datasources, one bean of them mark as @Primary

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.mysql")
public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.postgres")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource postgresDataSource() {                
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().              
            build();
}
```

Your application.properties should looks like this:

```
datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_demo
datasource.mysql.username=root
datasource.mysql.password=root
datasource.mysql.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

datasource.postgres.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
datasource.postgres.username=postgres
datasource.postgres.password=postgres
datasource.postgres.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: A minor improvement: you don't need to specify the driver class name when using MySQL or Postgres as Spring Boot will figure it out automatically based on the url